# Cannot import generic/freebsd11 vagrant box

Tags: windows, vagrant

I'm trying to import vagrant box using the following commands on Windows:

`vagrant init generic/freebsd11`

`vagrant up`

But I'm getting the following output:

`Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...`
`==> default: Box 'generic/freebsd11' could not be found. Attempting to find and install...`
    `default: Box Provider: virtualbox`
    `default: Box Version: >= 0`
`The box 'generic/freebsd11' could not be found or`
`could not be accessed in the remote catalog. If this is a private`
`box on HashiCorp's Vagrant Cloud, please verify you're logged in via`
`vagrant login`. Also, please double-check the name. The expanded`<br>` URL and error message are shown below:`

`URL: ["https://vagrantcloud.com/generic/freebsd11"]`
`Error: schannel: next InitializeSecurityContext failed: Unknown error (0x80092012) - The revocation`
`function was unable to check revocation for the certificate.`

Using Vagrant version 2.2.19

Windows 10 build 1809 x64

Virtualbox

Comment: Actually I've solved the problem. The issue was my anti-virus software (Kaspersky). After temporarily disabling web anti-virus component, the problem was gone.